# ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {})

Tags: cassandra

I am running Cassandra in 3 docker containers - and everything works. Until I do a `drop table tablename`;

Then I get: `('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts', {})`

Could it be anything with the replication_factor?

```
CREATE KEYSPACE keyspacename
     WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor' : 3 };
```

Regards

Comment: What happens if you change the replication_factor to 1 and then drop the table? Based on the message, it sounds like the host cannot be reached that is running the cqlsh session...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem was that I was using a datafolder (docker -v ...) on the host system. This data folder did contain old data - and obviously Cassandra was not able to handle old databases.

Comment: I have same problem with cassandra, How can handle this error?!

Comment: I had this running in a test environment, there fore I could just delete the data folder.

Comment: I think deleting data folder is not reasonable way to solve this problem!

Comment: Agree, but it helped me in test environment. Please write back if you find a solution.

Comment: I solved this problem with one or two restarting os and turn off and turn on DSE service :)